# mysql count the sum of all rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, aggregate-functions

I have a mysql table that has a number of rows, and in each row a field called "value",
the field value will differ from row to row.
What I want, is to select all the rows and count the sum of all the "value" fields.

any idea?

Comment: To show us the table do 'desc tablename' where tablename is the name of your table, ie 'desc tbl'

Comment: if you used google `select all the rows and count the sum of all the "value" fields mysql` would be easier then logging on and taking the time to ask your question

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
SELECT    SUM(value)
FROM      myTable
```

If you have multiple columns to return, simply add each non-aggregate (i.e., summed) row to the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT    firstName, lastName, SUM(value)
FROM      myTable
GROUP BY  firstName, lastName
```

Comment: @med, that isn't enough information... What is that code supposed to be? What is `$q`?

Comment: It should do exactly what you are asking. Give it a try!

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT SUM(`value`) FROM `your_table`
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT SUM(value) as total FROM table;

$row['total'];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT SUM(value)
    FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

What you'll want is the `GROUP`-function named [SUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum).

Answer (score 0):

This query will return the sum of `value` and the number of rows count:

```
SELECT count(*), sum(value) FROM tablename
```