# Getting SUM by adding time in PHP

Tags: php, timer

I need a MySQL query for the following. I have a table of time duration as such below:

```
`hsncs_tbl`

+----+-----------------+
| Id |  time_duration  |
+----+-----------------+
| 1  | 0:12            |
 ---- -----------------
| 2  | 0:18            |
 ---- -----------------
```

Using a MySQL query, I need to be able to calculate these time duration. So from the table above I would get the answer of 0:30.

I tried this code many times, but still not working

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(time_duration))) FROM hsncs_tbl
```

Here's the screenshot of my code together with the output.

[image: Screen shot]

Related questions:

[Sum of time in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553148/sum-of-time-in-php/22553578?noredirect=1#22553578)

[How to get the sum of time from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22529300/how-to-get-the-sum-of-time-from-database/22529956?noredirect=1#22529956)

[How to get the sum of time from database in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526524/how-to-get-the-sum-of-time-from-database-in-php?noredirect=1#comment34282725_22526524)

[How to display the sum of time from database using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495528/how-to-display-the-sum-of-time-from-database-using-php/22495679?noredirect=1#22495679)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054943/calculate-sum-time-with-mysql  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329458/mysql-how-to-sum-times

Comment: This might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131197/mysql-count-the-sum-of-all-rows

Comment: You should generally edit your old question. I’ll merge its answers into this one.

Answer (score 1):

try this one query in mysql

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(time_duration))) FROM yourTable;
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following SQL Query:---

```
SELECT SUM(time_duration) FROM table_name;
```

I hope that it will work according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
`sum(time_duration) as time_duration`
```

in your Mysql query.

Answer (score 0):

try this assuming time_duration is varchar column :

```
   select TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_FORMAT(time_duration, '%H:%i')))),'%H:%i') time_duration 
  from table1;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a764/1)

Ops: i guessed you have Hours and minutes , if you have minutes and seconds just change the format.